# Free tools for drawing out GUI

Tags: user-interface

What are some free/low budget/open source GUI design tools that you have used?  Any recommendations?

Comment: I guess I could use Visio (eeewwww).

Answer (score 3):

- [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/) is an excellent quick GUI design tool
- [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) is an amazing GUI design tool (Mac only)

Comment: Axure is another pretty good one